# Proving $ 1 + 2+...+n=n(n+1)/2$ using induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

**Base case:** $n=1$

**Left-hand side:** $1$
**Right hand side:** $1(1+1)/2=1$

Therefore, base case holds true.

**Induction hypothesis:** Assume its true for $n=k$, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$;

$$1 + 2+\cdots +k=k(k+1)/2$$

Then,

$$1+2+3+\cdots +(k+1) = (k+1)(k+2)/2$$

Hence, by induction hypothesis, $$ 1 + 2+...+n=n(n+1)/2$$ is true $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you want people to comment on your proof, it is better to tag your question "proof-verification"

Comment: @ArnaudD. sorry about that, i updated the tag

Comment: Probably because a quick google would have given him hundreds of results.

Comment: You seem to present no proof that $1+2+3+\cdots +(k+1)=(k+1)(k+2)/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is technically correct, but I would write it slightly more verbosely:

**Base case: $n=1$**

LHS: $1$

RHS: $\frac{1(1+1)}{2}=1$

So the base case holds

**Inductive Step**

We now assume that it holds for $n=k$, that is to say that: $$1+2+\ldots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ and we want to prove it holds for $n=k+1$, that is to say that: $$1+2+\ldots+k+(k+1)=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}2$$

We start from the LHS and attempt to prove it equals the RHS: \begin{align}1+2+\ldots+k+(k+1)&=(1+2+\ldots+k)+(k+1)\\
&=\frac{k(k+1)}2+(k+1)\tag{$\dagger$}\\
&=\frac{k(k+1)}2+\frac{2(k+1)}2\\
&=\frac{k(k+1)+2(k+1)}2\\
&=\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}2\end{align}

Therefore the inductive hypothesis holds

---

$(\dagger)$: Here we use our assumption that the statement is true for $n=k$ and so we can replace $1+2+\ldots +k$ with $\frac{k(k+1)}2$

Comment: so u always add (k+1) to both sides, is that correct?

Comment: For this question, yes because the next term is $(k+1)$ higher than the previous term

Comment: oh k thanks, so basically u add k+1 when he previous term is not higher than k+1

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. For inductive proofs, we assume the statement holds for $n=k$, and attempt to prove that it also holds for $n=k+1$. In this case, when $n=k$ we have $\frac{k(k+1)}2$ ad when $n=k+1$ we have $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}2$

Comment: yea i got that but i dont get why u are adding k+1 to k(k+1)/2

Comment: I've added some clarification to my answer - see if what I'm doing makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
1+2+3+....+k+(k+1) & = & (1+2+....+k) + (k+1) \\
 & =  & (k+1)\frac{k}{2} + (k+1) \\
 & =  & (k+1)(\frac{k}{2} + 1) \\
 & = & (k+1)\frac{k+2}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but perhaps you should be a bit more clear when you use the IH. That is:

$$1+2+3+\cdots+k+(k+1) = (1+2+3+\cdots+k) + (k+1) \\ = {k(k+1)\over 2} + (k+1)= {k(k+1) + 2(k+1)\over 2} = {(k+1)(k+2)\over 2}$$

or something like that...